# Creating a new table by mapping the values of two different table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle database. I have two different tables and one column from these tables has the same name but the values are represented in a differently as shown in the demo tables below. Actually, these values are nothing but same. For example, in one table the value is `abc` and in other tables, the value is `abc_I`. These two tables not necessary to have the same number of columns and rows.

Table1:-

```
 1    2    3    4
-------------------
-     -    -    abc
-     -    -    xyz
-     -    -    hi
-     -    -    hello
```

Table2:-

```
 1    2    3    4     5   6 
----------------------------
-     -    -    abc_I  -   -
-     -    -    xyz_I  -   -
-     -    -    hi II  -   -
-     -    -    hey I  -   -
```

I want to create the new table from these tables where `abc` maps with `abc_I`. I have no idea how it works, I heard about functional mapping but could not able to find an example for this. Can someone let me know how it works?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: And you need to specify what ***different manner*** mean. what is the logic will allow you make the match

Comment: Is the Table1 value always the first word in the Table2 value (separated by space or `_`) as in your example? Or are they just arbitrary values that do not necessarily have any part in common, e.g. `xxx` might map to `yyy`? Maybe you could populate a third table with two columns and join through that.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes, the table1 value always the first word in the table2. some time separated by space and sometimes with _ . But it might be possible that there are multiple values in table two for example `abc_I, abc_II` and I want to map `abc` from table1 to `abc_I` of table2